# WPF Adorner Transforms

Tags: wpf, transform, adorner

I am building a control, where the user can "draw" resizable rectangles that are laid over the content. To resize those rectangles, I use an Adorner on top of them which contains 4 Thumbs to change the size of the rectangle.

The problem is, that this control is is "zoomable", meaning a ScaleTransform is applied to the whole control depending on a zoom factor. The Thumbs in the Adorner are affected by this ScaleTransform as well.

But I need them to keep their size, independent of the zoom factor.
I tried putting the Adorners in a Layer of another non-transformed control instead of the rectangle-layer, but this didn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Andrej

Answer (score 0):

I also find this question on MSDN: [How to exclude scaleTransform from GeneralTransform in Adorner GetDesiredTransform method.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ff1764d7-9012-43bf-a0c9-09c5c0242f91/), this is good because also there is some example code.